# 0.10110111011110... is irrational.

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics

How can I prove that this number is irrational?

I wrote it like this, but I don't know if it's right.

$$\frac{100}{9} \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{10^m - 1}{10^{(m + 1)(m + 2)/2}} =0.10110111011110...$$

Comment: If it's rational, its decimal representation repeats at some point.

Comment: Nice, is there any way to simplify that representation?

Comment: If we look at the answer, not the formula, this number is irrational.  Because the numbers are not repeated. I mean $$10110111011110111110...$$

Comment: Is this number important for something? it appears in some cool problem?

Comment: It may be easier to look at the difference of your number from $1/9 = 0.1\bar{1}$, which would be $0.01001000100001...$

Comment: Your question is the cool problem that it appears in.

Comment: Thank you guys!